# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this error and I have no idea how to fix it. I have java 7. Thank you in advance. I am new to codding and I dont have any past experience at all, I have done the very basic on paper programing but still. Also what do I have to do to test this application inside the android emulator? Thanks

```
   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.> 
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

---

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.lightcurb.example" >

<!-- SDK feature -->
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
android:required="true" />

<application
android:name=".LCExampleApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

---

```
 <activity
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.indooratlas.android.sdk.API_KEY"
    android:value="c24c139a-0fd8-4072-b92d-440f1369a413"/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.indooratlas.android.sdk.API_SECRET"
        android:value="jU)0v5VVdUGfpE69DUS!zLmqVhA1wiPNymesYonp6XSArIshOSfYKbhJP9v6zIpdl8U9hOhrgQiPWYYjwSWUjgjDlbi44MNu0P52dwglirV0qTAWFfY7sj)ClhXp80i1"/>
</application>
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lightcurb.example"
minSdkVersion 18
targetSdkVersion 21
versionCode 9
versionName "1.0.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-         rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.indooratlas.android:indooratlas-android-sdk:2.0.2-beta@aar'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.radiusnetworks:AndroidIBeaconLibrary:0.7.7@aar'
compile 'com.lightcurb.sdk:LightcurbSDK:1.0.1@aar'
}
repositories{
maven {
    url "http://indooratlas-ltd.bintray.com/mvn-public"
   }
}
```

Comment: it says UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: before Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2